# How to Customize the title of the customized UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios

I have customized the UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
UIButton *loginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
loginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46.0, 34.0);
[loginBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loginPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[loginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *finishedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:loginBtn];

[finishedButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = finishedButton;
```

But now **i can not see the title with "Login"**, it's blank on the button, it seems that the "setTitle:" did not work.
Could anybody tell me why? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTitle:` **did** work, you just haven't read the documentation carefully enough. Use `setBackgroundImage:` instead of `setImage:` as the latter overrides `setTitle:`, but the former doesn't (and that's what you want). So instead of

```
[loginBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

write

```
[loginBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            ^
            +- background!
```

and you should be fine to go.

Comment: It works! Now the title appears. Thanks a lot! But the font on the button is too large, can i set the font?

Comment: @trey.lin You're welcome. By the way, you're supposed to accept answers that helped. Yes, you can set the font: try `loginBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];` or similar.